# Trying to replace graphics resources in a PDF - PDFBox 2.0.8

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to manipulate image resources in some PDF files; the workflow is: extract image resources -> process each -> replace old ones with the new.

Simple task really, I have working code for extracting and replacing, but when I replace, the new file size is nearly twice the original.

To replace the images, I use `PDResources.put(COSName, PDXObject)`. Any ideas what would cause the size increase in the resulting document? It happens even if I completely omit the middle step in the workflow to process each image resource.

```
public static void PDFBoxReplaceImages() throws Exception {
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Users\\Markus\\workspace\\pdf-test\\book.pdf"));
    PDPageTree list = document.getPages();

    for (PDPage page : list) {
        PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
        for (COSName c : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {

            PDXObject o = pdResources.getXObject(c);

            if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {

                counter++;

                String path = "C:\\Users\\Markus\\workspace\\pdf-test\\images\\"+counter+".png";

                PDImageXObject newImg = 
                    PDImageXObject.createFromFile(path, document);
                pdResources.put(c, newImg);
            }
        }
    }

    document.save("C:\\Users\\Markus\\workspace\\pdf-test\\book.pdf");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the middle step in the workflow"*?

Comment: "extract image resources -> process each -> replace old ones with the new" - by the 'middle step' I meant the 'process each' step - i.e. changing the image in some way.

Comment: Can you share a sample pdf? There are multiple possible reasons. E.g. if you have the same image I  multiple places (for example a background or a header icon), the actual image data may be present only once I  the pdf. Your code, though, makes each such image use have its own image data in the pdf. Or there may be different pdf compression settings. Or or or...

Comment: I've been using 'REST in practice' book, but even [this](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiA443cxLLXAhXQDuwKHVGqDsAQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dccomics.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fimce%2F2015%2F09-SEP%2FBatmanDayActivityPages.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1az8MqRAfLkULeHPZrhWS4) simple batman comic is 4mb bigger after I replace the images - granted, some resources repeat in this one but they're negligible in size.

None of the images in the REST in practice book repeat though. Which is why I can't figure out what's happening.

Comment: Please upload the modified dccomics PDF file to a sharehoster for analysis.